# Updating SQL column value results in data loss in another table

Tags: sql, sql-update, data-loss

I have a table in which I want to update a specifc column value:

```
UPDATE [db].[table1]
SET Name = 'coder'
WHERE Nr = 14
```

When I perform this update, I get data loss in another column of another table in the same database (in which the value is updated as well).

Does anybody know if there is a common way to prevent such data loss?

Comment: Probably a trigger causing the problem.

Comment: Could be a virtual column.

Comment: Without knowing what "get data loss" means, guessing is all anyone can do. That usually is not an effective means of solving a problem. It is concerning that you have a **schema** named "db" and a table named "table1".